# why do we use pointer to 1-D array or multidimensional array

Tags: arrays, c, pointers

Recently i was going through concepts pointers , encountered with pointer to an array.
so my questions are:-

1. why we use pointer to an array ,though we can use access content directly using array?
2. my second questions is related to following code.

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{    int *p; 
      
    int (*ptr)[5]; 
    int arr[5];
      
    p = arr;
      
    ptr = &arr; 
      
    printf("p = %p, ptr = %p\n", p, ptr);
      
    p++; 
    ptr++;
      
    printf("p = %p, ptr = %p\n", p, ptr);
      
    return 0;
}
```

I know (*ptr)(5) points to an array of size 5.so here what ptr++ points to, is it pointing to something that i haven't defined?

---

3. My last question is about pointer to multi dimensional array.
   somewhere i saw they used *(*(arr+i)+j) for dereferencing or accessing the value , why is that ?though we can write arr[i][j] in place of that and it is way more easy to write.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> why we use pointer to an array

They don't have many direct uses, they are mostly there to keep the language consistent. Usually we use them without realizing, as in the case of

```
void func (int x[5][5]);
```

Here `x` silently decays into a pointer to the first element. The first element is an array of `int [5]` so we actually end up with a `int (*)[5]` type.

> my second questions is related to following code.

`p` performs pointer arithmetic of `int` items (likely 4 bytes) but `ptr` performs pointer arithmetic on `int [5]` items (likely 4*5=20 bytes).

> My last question is about pointer to multi dimensional array. somewhere i saw they used ((arr+i)+j) for dereferencing or accessing the value , why is that

It's needlessly unreadable clutter, avoid such code.

> though we can write arr[i][j] in place of that and it is way more easy to write.

Indeed. For example you can dynamically allocate a 5x5 int array as:

```
int (*arr)[5] = malloc( sizeof(int[5][5]) );
```

Then access it with `arr[i][j]` and free it with `free(arr)`.

Comment: if i want to store something ptr++,can i do that?if yes how?

Comment: @YogeshSatyam You'd need an array of arrays then, as in my malloc example.